# I'm trying to import but jupyter notebook dies

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

```
from skimage import io
```

I'm trying to import but jupyter notebook dies

the kernel appears to have died. it will restart automatically.

Comment: Does it die in a Python terminal with the same environment?

Comment: Have you tried it outside of jupyter notebook? can you import and use the library properly?

Comment: I tried via anaconda prompt and there is no problem, only jupyter appears in notebook

Answer (score 0):

try google colab instead, I had same issue and it got resolved with google colab.